# belongsTo relationship & filtering in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, relationship, belongs-to, cakephp-model

I'm a newbie to cakePHP and I've taken on creating a very small "status reporting" project, that would allow a user to report their current status on a project that they were assigned on.

I'm currently using the acl, auth, and session components to allow for multiple tier users to manage one another with an admin creating users, projects, and assigning them to one another. I have also fixed it so that when a user is logged in and goes to add a "status" that their login session automatically takes care of the "user_id" for the status:

```
$this->data['Status']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

What I need help doing now is filter the options for the project that the user can pick to add a "status" to.

I currently have a setup with a table that holds the relationships between users and projects named *projects_users* with *id, project_id, user_id* as fields. But, after baking this setup, when the user is adding a "status" the drop down menu provides all projects rather than strictly the ones they are "assigned to."

**I would like to filter the user's options to the projects that they are assigned to.** Is there considerable more relationships I should be setting up or is this a pretty easy little function to write? Any help would be greatly appreciated and if I have left out information, I'd be glad to post anything else.

Here is the **Status Model** setup:

```
class Status extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Status';
//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Project' => array(
        'className' => 'Project',
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
}
```

My **User Model** looks like this:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Group' => array(
        'className' => 'Group',
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

var $hasMany = array(
    'Status' => array(
        'className' => 'Status',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);


var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Project' => array(
        'className' => 'Project',
        'joinTable' => 'projects_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'project_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the database, You should have a column called **project_id** in the **user** table that is associated with the **project** table's **id** column.

Then, in your User model, you should create a hasMany relationship with the Project model.

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $hasMany = 'Project';
}
```

Now, when you fetch a particular user, you will get all projects that the user is associated with.

Comment: Is my current table project_users that holds the relationships of the users and the projects an incorrect way of setting this up? It currently holds project_id and user_id. Ideally, I'd like to keep the users table clean from their assigned projects and there is the potential to have multiple users on projects.

Right now, when I retrieve a User, I do see their associated projects but, I'm restricting the lowest user to only be able to add a "status." Therefore, I'd like to retrieve the sessions's active user's associated projects there.

I'm adding my User Model to my original post as well.

Comment: this is a HABTM table. thats fine if there is a N:M relation. seems like the case here. you need to use a custom join here to get those relations in a find statement. see the cookbook for details on this

Comment: @Curtis Please show the code you are using to retrieve the projects when adding a status.